# Math behind data modelling

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse

What kind of mathematical concepts (e,g Graph Theory) are a requisite reading for a through understanding of data modelling and data warehousing concepts and design?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say any are *requisite* necessarily.  I have found the following useful however:

1. [The Relational Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model).  The theory on which pretty much all RDBMS' are based.
2. [First Order Predicate Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).  The theoretical underpinning of the relational model
3. [Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).  Good, among other things, for understanding the different relations among sets: union, intersection, difference.  These all have direct analogues in the Relational Model.
4. [Graph Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory).  Probably the one I found least useful for data modelling per se.  However (1) I'd already covered those above first, and (2) it is useful for understanding data model traversal (e.g. transitive closure).

I would heavily caveat all above.  I am neither mathematician nor computer scientist, so am coming at it from an empirical, practitioner's standpoint.  Someone better versed in those fields can no doubt provide recommendations based on much stronger theoretical foundations.

As well as / instead of the theory there are some good books that combine theoretical underpinnings with practical considerations; e.g.

1. [SQL and Relational Theory](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022879.do) (Chris Date).  Excellent book which presents the theory well.  Only downside: Date is no fan of SQL and makes his point repeatedly which does get a bit tiresome.  But it's a great book nonetheless.
2. [Data Modeling Essentials](http://store.elsevier.com/Data-Modeling-Essentials/Graeme-Simsion/isbn-9780126445510/) (Simsion & Witt).  Really good book.  Also covers the theory well, in particular the different Normal Forms in the relational model.

hth.

Comment: Nice answer thought I wouldn't quite put that first sentence that way.  Getting oneself educated on the first three out of your four, is requisite to understanding that the formal maths in there actually have very little to do with information modeling as it is usually understood (ER, UML class diagrams, and various NIAM-based methods such as Halpin ORM), and which is typically _conceptual_ in nature, that is, deliberately INformal (in varying degrees).  Mathematical foundation are usually quite the opposite, that is, extremely formal, iow, NON-informal.

Comment: @Erwin: thanks.  Good point about formality: learning to reason in a formal way is challenging but valuable.